# Single file - two modules

Tags: python, python-import

Everytime I think I understand the details of Python's import (finally!), something new brings me back to reality. Please take a look at this simple example:

File `t1.py`:

```
import t2

x = "waiting for init"

def init():
    global x
    x = "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    print("x =", x)
    t2.print_x()
```

Taking care not to use the incorrect `from t1 import x`, here is file `t2.py`:

```
import t1

def print_x():
    print("t1.x =", t1.x)
```

Anyway, the output is not what I expected:

```
$ python3 t1.py 

x = OK
t1.x = waiting for init
```

So `x in t1` differs from `t1.x`!

---

After some investigation this version of `t2.py` helped me a little:

```
import t1

def print_x():
    import sys
    print(sys.modules['t1'].x)
    print(sys.modules['__main__'].x)
```

the output of those two prints is:

```
waiting for init
OK
```

---

I find it confusing. A single file `t1.py` is at the same time known as two different modules: `t1` and `__main__`. Could you please explain me the meaning of it? What must be changed in the posted code to get `t1.x = "OK"`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it affects this specific issue, but you have circular imports -- t1 imports t2, and t2 imports t1.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Yes, you have two in-memory modules created from *t1.py* source.

The reason for this is how Python's import system handles `__main__` module. Basically, it doesn't do this.

`__main__` module is not imported via Python's standard import mechanism but is initialized similarly to how built-ins do.

That's why, when `t1` is import from `t1` in your code, you actually get it imported **once more**.

It's easy to make an experiment. Change the code of your `t1.py` module to this:

```
import t2

x = "waiting for init"

if __name__ == "t1":
    print("t1.x = ", x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("__main__.x =", x)
```

And you will see the next printed in console:

```
t1.x =  waiting for init
__main__.x = waiting for init
```

Now comment the first line in this module, and you will get this:

```
__main__.x = waiting for init
```

So, in first case, module `t1` is firstly initialized (its code is executed) by interpreter's startup mechanizm as `__main__`, and then t1 is initialized by Python's import system from t2 module (thus is executed once more).

In the second case, the module is only initialized by interpreter startup mechanizm.

PS. Nice catch from @ShadowRanger in comment below: printing `sys.modules` at the end of the script will show you something like this:

```
<module '__main__' from 't1.py'>
<module 't1' from 'D:\\Projects\\python_test\\t1.py'>
```

demonstrating that modules are created from the same source.

Comment: Another useful test: In the `__main__` handling code, do: `import sys`, `print("__main__ same as t1?", sys.modules['__main__'] is sys.modules['t1'])` (this relies on `t1` having been cached as a result of importing `t2`). It will report `False`; it would only report `True` if both cache entries were initialized to exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The sentence "... imported once more" is the key here. The conclusion for me is "never import the entry point file" (file with `if __name__ == '__main__'`). Right?

Comment: @VPfB File with `if _name__ == '__main__'` is not necessary a main script. You can use this condition e.g. for testing purposes, and the main purpose for this code is to separate module's behavior in both cases (when module is imported, and when module is run as a main script). So the right answer would be not importing the module when it is already run as a script. That situation actually makes little sense, and basically shows application's architecture flaws.